# Azure NSG not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, network-security-groups

I have an Azure external loadbalancer with a backend pool that contains 1 kubernetes master server and has a load balancing rule on port 443.

I added a rule with priority 500 to deny all traffic coming from the internet on port 443 to the kubernetes master server. Works fine

I added a rule with priority 400 to accept traffic coming from a certain public ip because I only want to be able to connect from that ip. I expected that I  should be able to connect but I can't.

If I change the rule that accepts traffic from the source ip to internet then it works fine. 
What am I missing?

Kind Regards

Comment: Did you add the incoming IP as your IP or the Load balancers IP? I believe you need to set it to the LoadBalancers IP and port you are connecting through.

Comment: Do you have any internal firewall rules set up that might be blocking traffic?

Answer (score 0):

> "I added a rule with priority 400 to accept traffic coming from a
>   certain public ip because I only want to be able to connect from that
>   ip. I expected that I should be able to connect but I can't.
>
> If I change the rule that accepts traffic from the source ip to
>   internet then it works fine. What am I missing?"

Things that you might have missed:

1. Make sure you are not specifying the source port !! It would be
   taken from a pool of available ports referred to as ephemeral ports
   from the client that you initiate the connection.
2. You are blocking the Allow Azure Load Balancer IP which is a default rule.
   Load Balancer health probes originate from the IP address 168.63.129.16 and must not be blocked for probes to mark your instance up. Review probe source IP address for details.

Create a separate rule to allow this IP as this is a MSFT IP you should have no issues allowing this.** Before deny all (Priority <500)

That should fix your issue for sure !!

**Diagnosis & RCA**:
Why this is happening, the Azure Load balancer Probe IP is being blocked and hence the backend server is being marked as unhealthy by the load balancer.